# htaccess not following file hierarchy

Tags: .htaccess

We are currently redirecting a number of pages on our website and they are not following the hierarchy of the htaccess file. We have structured the file so that it follows individual redirects initially and then if the page url does not match any of the individual redirects there is a catch all;

```
#Individual redirect
RedirectMatch 301 ^/de/gemeinschaften/utilities$ /community/utitlies-nce/

#Catch All
RewriteRule ^de/  / [R=301,L]
```

But when you load;

http://www.website.co.uk/de/gemeinschaften/utilities

it redirects to;

http://www.website.co.uk/

and not;

http://www.website.co.uk/community/utitlies-nce/

Comment: Better you use `RewriteRule` for all redirects and test in a new browser to clear cache.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava can I check that it would be correct to use RewriteRule 301 ^/de/gemeinschaften/utilities$ /community/utitlies-nce/

Comment: It would be: `RewriteRule ^de/gemeinschaften/utilities/?$ /community/utitlies-nce/ [L,NC,R=301]`